# My render is looking transparent

Tags: rendering

My render is looking transparent. This is how it's looking in the layout:

[image]

And when I render it, it's like transparent or something

[image]

Please help me. I started to learn Blender yesterday with a YouTube video tutorial, and I'm getting these problems.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you attach your blend file? https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Hello, maybe check the Object panel > Visibility > Holdout option?

Comment: i tried to turn off hold out but it didnt work

Answer (score 2):

Check if *Holdout* option is enabled, disable it:

[image]